# CGSize sizeWithFont not returning correct height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel that is correctly word wrapping if I force its frame height to be tall enough. However, I want it to dynamically find the proper height, and the `sizeWithFont` method isn't doing this; that method just creates a single line in my label:

```
CGSize subtitleSize=[subtitle sizeWithFont:subtitleFont forWidth:maxwidth lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Then I use the same text, font and size from this function:

```
        UILabel *subLabel=[[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, maxwidth, subtitleSize.height)]autorelease];
        subLabel.font=subtitleFont;
        subLabel.text=subtitle;
        subLabel.numberOfLines=0;
        subLabel.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

It looks like it should all work and give me a size which i then use. But the height of the size is always just one line for the label.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I too was trying to use sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode: initially.  I assumed that since it only asked for width that it would use the max float height.  However, the documentation clearly states: "Returns the size of the string if it were to be rendered with the specified font and line attributes on a single line."  The single line part is the trick.  You have to use one of the size methods that specifies constrainedToSize.

Comment: @MattBecker you are a scholar and also a gentleman.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you may use this

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode;
```

max the size in constrainedToSize

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(maxwidth, CGFLOAT_MAX);
```

Comment: but I am not constraining it to a height; that is the point, to *receive* the size

Comment: While it seems hack-ish, this appears to be an appropriate approach. [Apple's docs on the `forWidth` version](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893-CH3-SW7) suggest it only returns something approximate to `width x line height` for the given font, no matter the string.

Answer (score 1):

First, check i fthe text in the **subtitle** variable is long as you expect. Then try to use this method to calculate text size:

```
CGSize subtitleSize = [subtitle sizeWithFont:subtitleFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(maxwidth, 1000000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

In this code you are calculating text size to the maximum width and "infinite" height.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can give one bigger font size manually, that worked for me.